# Automatically provision Azure Pipelines agents?

Tags: azure-pipelines

Say I have a Azure DevOps instance. Now I would like it to be possible that whenever I run a job, a new container with the `agent` software will be launched on one of a set of machines so that the job can run on it, and stop once the job ends.

In Jenkins for example, this is possible. You can run jobs on a `podTemplate` agent, so that each time the job will run, a new pod will start in a k8s cluster, running the agent software along with any other containers you specify.

So I was wondering - is this possible in Azure DevOps in any way? If not, how can I evaluate the feasibility of writing an extension that will allow such capability?

### EDIT

My Azure DevOps instance is in an air-gapped environment - no internet - so it isn't possible to use Azure services or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, in Azure DevOps, a VMSS agent pool may fulfill your demands.

Azure virtual machine scale sets let you create and manage a group of load balanced VMs. The number of VM instances can automatically increase or decrease in response to demand or a defined schedule. Scale sets provide high availability to your applications, and allow you to centrally manage, configure, and update a large number of VMs. With virtual machine scale sets, you can build large-scale services for areas such as compute, big data, and container workloads: [Azure virtual machine scale sets overview - Azure Virtual Machine Scale Sets | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview)

1.Create your VMSS with Azure Subscription

[image]

2.Connect to your VMSS by adding agent pool in Azure DevOps

[image]